# Is it possible to use a function parameter as part of a jquery statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am hoping to produce a jQuery statement that is partly comprised of text passed to the function as a parameter.

I.E:

My goal statement would be:

```
$('#object1.object').next('.object');
```

This statement would retrieve the element that was the next element with a class of "object" from the DOM.

But I want to generate this statement dynamically - specifically the .next part - So I create this function:

```
function getNextPrevObj(state){
  $('#object1.object').state('.object');
}
```

and call it with:

```
getNextPrevOb("next");
```

But as I would expect the .state throws an unknown function error - and attempting to substitute it as a string also fails:

```
($'#object1.object').+state+('.object');
```

Am I simply using the wrong syntax for the replacement of the function with the parameter - or is this not possible?

Thanks.

Comment: `$('#object1.object')[state]('.object');`

Comment: Thanks Rob W - worked perfectly.